# How do I make the bot dm me with a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So I have an easter egg command. If someone says `+founder`, my bot replies that the user found an easter egg. But I want the bot to dm me if anyone runs the command.

Here's my code :

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'founder',
    description: "easter egg",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('You found a easter egg!! Don\'t tell anyone else.....');
    }
}
```

And here's what in `main.js`

```js
if (command === 'founder') {
    client.commands.get('founder').execute(message, args);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to grab yourself as a `User`/`GuildMember` and use [`send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send) to send a message:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'founder',
    description: 'easter egg',
    async execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send('You found an easter egg!! Don\'t tell anyone else.....');
        const me = await message.guild.members.fetch('YOUR ID HERE');
        me.send(`${message.author} found an easter egg!`);
    }
}
```